# Unable to send gifs using Twilio

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to send this gif - https://media.giphy.com/media/YVBC4HdSpB7z2/giphy.gif - using Twilio but I am getting this error - `Channel did not accept given content. Please see Channel specific error message for more information`.

This is my code -

```
try{

            $client = new Client(env('TWILIO_SID'), env('TWILIO_TOKEN'));
            $send = $client->messages->create(
                "whatsapp:".$my_phone_number, // Text this number
                array(
                    'from' => "whatsapp:".env('TWILIO_NUMBER'),
                    'body' => 'hey',
                    'mediaUrl' => 'https://media.giphy.com/media/YVBC4HdSpB7z2/giphy.gif',
                    'contentType' => ['image/gif']
                )
            );

        }catch (\Exception $exception){

        }
```

The content-type is image/gif, which is acceptable by Twilio. So what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for Twilio WhatsApp supported MIME types:

[Accepted Content Types for Media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types)

It calls out the following:

> The Twilio API for WhatsApp supports sending and receiving images,
>   audio, PDF files, and video. The following formats are currently
>   supported:
>
> Images: JPG, JPEG, PNG Audio: MP3, OGG, AMR Documents: PDF Video: MP4